# Uniqueness of maximal subgroup and order being a power of a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite group. If $G$ has only one maximal subgroup (a maximal subgroup is a proper subgroup $M$ that given a subgroup $H$ of $G$, $M \subset H \subset G$ implies that $H = M$ or $H = G$), prove that the order of $G$ is a power of a prime.

I've been stuck in this exercise for a few days now and just can't solve it.

I tried applying Cauchy to $p$ and $q$ primes that divide the order of $G$ and also to analyse maximal subgroups containing the generated subgroups of the elements of order $p$ and $q$ given by Cauchy's theorem, but without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1. A group $G$ cannot be expressed as a union of proper subgroups if and only if $G$ is cyclic.

Step 2. A finite group that has a unique maximal subgroup cannot be expressed as a union of proper subgroups.

Step 3. If $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, and $p$ is a prime dividing $n$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $n/p$ that is maximal.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily difficult to me.

Comment: @the_fox: Maybe; but your solution only gets you to prove the group is cyclic, eliding the rest. This one has some extra implications: for instance, a group with exactly two maximal subgroups is cyclic (of order $p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}$ for primes $p\neq q$).

Comment: Once you see that the group must be cyclic, I think that it is almost impossible to miss the rest of the argument needed to establish that the group must be cyclic of prime-power order. (I am assuming here that anyone who attempts to do this problem knows beforehand the "fundamental theorem" of cyclic groups which describes their subgroup structure.)

Comment: @the_fox: difficulty is in the eye of the beholder. Your argument may require fewer steps, but it is ad hoc and does not get you anywhere in a slightly different situation. This one does. YMMV.

Comment: No problem, we can agree to disagree. But perhaps you could explain in your answer that the steps you suggest, if followed, actually achieve a bit more than what is asked.

Comment: @the_fox The steps I suggest achieve what the steps I suggest state. At this point, you seem to be suggesting that I must somehow incorporate into my answer that you think your answer is better. I'll pass.

Comment: My answer is, to me, clearly better than yours, but--surprise--I could not care less what you think about my answer or what you write in your answer about my answer. What I suggested you do is based on this bit you wrote yourself: "This one has some extra implications: for instance, a group with exactly two maximal subgroups is cyclic (...)". I suggested you include this in the main body of your answer. How is this hurting your answer or promoting mine? Don't see ghosts where there aren't any. It's unhealthy. Bye

Comment: @the_fox: And I don't really care what you think I should put in my answer, given that it is correct. So, yes, Bye.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Let $x \notin M$, where $M$ is the unique maximal subgroup. What can you say about $\langle x \rangle$?